# How do you mark/show the critical point (-1, 0) on Nyquist plot?

Tags: plotting, control-systems

I am trying to make the Nyquist plot of the function $\frac{200}{(s+1)(s+2)(s+3)}$ as below. However, I would like to see mark the critical point (-1, 0) on the plot so we can see clearly whether the plot encircles the point or not. 
I am curious to know how you usually do this? How to show the critical point easily?

```
NyquistPlot[TransferFunctionModel[200/((s + 1)*(s + 2)*(s + 3)), s]]
```

Comment: You can use the `Epilog` option: `Epilog -> {Red, PointSize[Large], Point[{-1, 0}]}` – just add this as the last argument of `NyquistPlot`. `NyquistPlot` has all the options that `Graphics` has. Note that `Epilog` is documented as an option under `Graphics` and not under `NyqustPlot`.  It also has its own page in the documentation.

Comment: Also, you can focus on the critical point with `PlotRange`, as in: `NyquistPlot[TransferFunctionModel[200/((s + 1)*(s + 2)*(s + 3)), s], PlotRange -> {{-5, 1}, {-1, 1}}, Epilog -> {Red, PointSize[Large], Point[{-1, 0}]}]`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just to get an answer on record.

```
NyquistPlot[TransferFunctionModel[200/((s + 1)*(s + 2)*(s + 3)), s], 
  Epilog -> {Red, AbsolutePointSize[5], Point[{-1, 0}]}]
```

[image: plot]